# overlapping background image

Tags: css, background-image

I have a table with a background image using css property background-image. In table I have some images using the `<img`. Images `<img` table are above the background image. I would like the background image overwrite the images `<img` as with the text. Is that possible?

Code Example:

```
<style>
#content { background-image:url("background-image.jpg"); background-repeat:repeat-y} 
</style>

<table id="content">
<tr>
  <td>Some text.....text.....text
    Image: <img src="quadrado.jpg" />
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"I would like to display the two images. The background image 
above the quadrado.jpg ! Like a watermark"
```

Sounds like you want an ***overlay***.   You can't do that with just CSS.
But you can come close by adding styles like so:

```
#content
{
    opacity:            0.8;
    -ms-filter:         "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
    filter:             alpha(opacity=80);
}
#content img
{
    opacity:            0.8;
    -ms-filter:         "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
    filter:             alpha(opacity=80);
}
```

.
For more of a true overlay, you'd need to code it into your HTML or use javascript to add it on the fly.

Take a look at **[this page](http://scratchpad2.com/public/OverlayFun3.htm)**.  It uses javascript to generate overlays for blocks with the class `OverlayTheBackground`.

There are also [jQuery plugins that are supposed to generate overlays](http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html).

---

<strike>Perhaps post a picture of what you want.</strike>

But, it *sounds* like all you need to do is add this style:

```
#content img {visibility: hidden;}
```

Comment: I would like to display the two images. The background image above the quadrado.jpg ! Like a watermark. Thanks

Comment: Oops, the demo page had a race condition, so it didn't always measure locations correctly (when pulling off the web instead of my intranet).  It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question completely, but if you want the background image to show through parts of the content images, you will need to use png's or gif's as they permit parts of the image to be transparent and jpg's don´t.